# DateTimePickers don't show the data

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

The database contains data about movie house(cinema's). The database contains this fields : Name of movie house, Name of movie, start time and date.

I have a problems with additional task. The program should generate a report for each
cinema in the order of the sessions on the specified date.

When I choosing a date in DatePickers, database doesn't show the first movie.

Example:

value of datetimePicker1 = 13.12.2018
value of datetimePicker2 = 16.12.2018

that database show information about 14,15,16.12.2018.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
  if (Convert.ToDateTime(tableDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value) >= dateTimePicker1.Value
    && Convert.ToDateTime(tableDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value) <= dateTimePicker2.Value)
      MessageBox.Show(tableDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() +
        "  || Movie theater:  " + tableDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
        " | Movie: " + tableDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Is it possible the dates have a time part? It could be that the first movie time is something like 13.12.2018 16:00:00? Then, this datetime is greater than 13.12.2018 0:00:00

Comment: No, its immpossible. "It could be that the first movie time is something like 13.12.2018 16:00:00? Then, this datetime is greater than 13.12.2018 0:00:00"-- this is my bug.

Comment: It would help if you added example data for your proplem. Also, have you tried debugging your code? [how to debug in visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Please make a change:
I was able to create a similar C# WindowsFormsApplication based on information you have provided and was able to replicate a similar bug and got it resolved with this:
Change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
```

To:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tableDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
```

Second:
If there is a blank line at the end of GridView, then you may need to add this line to Form1_Load event

```
tableDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```